# Will it possible to convert word doc to XML using Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I like to convert the data which I have in word document into XML using Spring Batch. 
If so can anyone help me with an example to understand in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a "Word-to-XML export library".
Create a one-step job: this step will be defined as a [TaskletStep](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/TaskletStep.html) and it calls "Word-to-XML export library" method useful to do conversion.

Comment: Want to do through web page ,will it possible?

Comment: SB is not related to your front-end: a job can be "launched" from a web page as well as from command-line. SB works behind. Your question is really too broad, please elaborate better, focus on a single problem and ask for help. My answer is generic due to nature of your question. You have to work more around SB, read official doc, buy a book or so on and came back later: we will be happy to help you!